# Query on column other than primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a partial set up to bring in iTunes sales data I receive daily. I want to display on my product pages etc. My products all have a primary key but this is not present on the iTunes sales data table so I need to do my lookup using the UPC column as that the next best unique identifier. It's probably very simple but how would I go about doing that?

```
 <% render @product.itunes_datas %>
```

is referencing the following controller/method:

```
 @itunes_datas = ItunesData.find (:all)
```

Do I just define another method in the controller?

I need this to be flexible if possible as product level lookups will be by UPC, whereas track level lookups will be via ISRC code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you get the UPC information from Apple, but as long as you have it, you can perform lookups on it using whichever of these methods you like the most:

```
ItunesData.where(:upc => 'UPC_Information_Here').all
ItunesData.find_all_by_upc('UPC_Information_Here')
```

They're exactly equivalent to each other and will find information based on the column you specify, rather than the primary key.

Comment: Thanks, that looks perfect! Is the column name the 'UPC_Information_Here' part? (I have a daily report from Apple that I'm importing into the db btw).

Comment: No, the column name is either in the symbol or method name. The more general case looks like either ```ItunesData.where(:column_name => 'column_data').all``` or ```ItunesData.find_all_by_column_name('column_data')```.

Comment: Hmmm, as i'm doing @product.itunes_datas it's still looking for a product_id in the itunes table: SELECT "itunes_data".* FROM "itunes_data" WHERE "itunes_data"."product_id" = 66

Comment: The default way Rails looks up association information is through the primary key, so saying ```@product.itunes_data``` will perform a primary key lookup. You can either change the key the association uses or not lookup the itunes_data from the product.

Comment: So drop in: set_primary_key :upc into the itunes_data Model? I really need to look up itunes_data on each product. The problem with changing the key like this is that when I perform a similar lookup at track level i'll need to work with the ISRC code....bundle downloads show up on UPC / single track downloads on an ISRC.

Comment: No, you probably want to define a new association in product.rb like this: has_many :upc_itunes_data, :class_name => 'ItunesData', :foreign_key => 'upc', :primary_key => 'barcode'

Comment: Oh, and to complicate things, my products table uses 'barcode' as the column name...

Comment: Try that new association code I posted and use @product.upc_itunes_data... it should select from the upc column of the ItunesData table using the product's barcode as the key.

Comment: Getting the correct SQL but now a partial error! I can probably suss that out though, thanks for your help!